# Fade in and Fade out between activities

Tags: android, textures, android-animation

I have got an app built in android studio where I fading in and out between different videos placed in a texture. I succeed to create the fade but it fades from the video to white instead of fading into the next texture with the new video

Here is my fade code:
Fade in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

Fade out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

And Im implementing it in my mainactivity like this:

```
view1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstVideoActivity.class);
        startActivity(startIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

    }
});
```

As it is right now it first fades to white and then shows the firstvideoActivity. How can I get it to rather fade between the different videos without first going into white

**UPDATE**

here is the other activity im changing to:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    Log.d("oncreateee","I");
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

    myTexture = findViewById(R.id.textureBackground);
    myTexture.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

    myTexture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }

            Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
    Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test1);

    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Ok I have now noticed this is a bug in kitkat (need to develop for that old system this time) Are there any other way creating transition that might work for kitkat?

Comment: consider doing animation on mediaplayer's view

Comment: I have tried to follow but in that case where do I do that? See my update above

Comment: Ok I have now noticed this is a bug in kitkat (need to develop for that old system this time) Are there any other way creating transition that might work for kitkat?